# Lightweight software, Notepad++ and Google Keep features

Tags: note-taking, cloud-service, markdown, notepad++

I am looking for a Web (at work, mobile, Mac) and/or desktop app (at home, Windows) with cloud sync that that behaves like Notepad++, but allows to text search through all the files edited in it.

In case I didn't make myself clear  - sometimes I need to edit code or write small snippets, but also make a lot of notes in Notepad++. The problem is, I very often can't find those notes when I need them.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.int64.io is a website to manage code. It's similar to jsfiddle.com and GitHub Gist.

It doesn't have a corresponding desktop app, but since it's web-based it works on any operating system.

- In the next release within a couple of weeks it will have an embedded code editor (I'm using Ace).
- When you create a snippet, the form has a "Notes" field so you can add notes related to that snippet.
- You can add tags to your snippets.
- Search is not available right now, but it's the next thing that will be implemented after the code editor is released. Expect to see it in about a month. When it's implemented, it'll be able to search through all of the snippets that you entered.

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of http://www.int64.io

Comment: Search has been implemented and is now available.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate your notes to Keep or Google Docs and keep your code in Notepad++. Also there are some Google Drive apps that let you edit code. If that's not enough, you can edit code and run it from a VPS from Koding

Answer (score 1):

You can try tiddlywiki. http://tiddlywiki.com/. Online syncing can be achieved with tiddlyspot.com. You can download and sync your notes anytime and anywhere you want.